# Programming in c dodgy if statements?

Tags: c, if-statement, multiplication

I'm writing code that reads the input for water consumption and displays the bill. the fixed price is $10. for the first 30 meters it costs $0.6 per meter, for the next 20 meters it costs $0.8, then the next 10 meters it cost $1.2 per meter and additional meters are $1.2 but for some reason my code asks the user to input a value and does nothing else. what am I doing wrong? Is it my if statements? I feel as though they are okay and my calculations may be the problem. here is the code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int watercom, fixedrate, first30, next20, next10, additional, firstcal, secondcal,thirdcal, fourthcal;

    printf("what is our water consumption?\n");
    scanf("%i\n",&watercom);

    fixedrate = 10;
    first30 = 0.6;
    next20 = 0.8;
    next10 = 1.0;
    additional = 1.2;

    firstcal = fixedrate * first30;
    secondcal = fixedrate * next20;
    thirdcal = fixedrate * next10;
    fourthcal = fixedrate * additional;

    if ( watercom <= 30)
        printf("your bill is %i", &firstcal);
    else if (watercom >= 31 && watercom  <= 50)
        printf("your bil is %i", &secondcal);
    else if (watercom >= 51 && watercom >= 60)
        printf("your bill is %i", &thirdcal);
    else if (watercom >= 61)
        printf("your water bill is %i", fourthcal);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should `watercom >= 60` be `watercom <= 60`?

Comment: In `first30 = 0.6;` you are assigning a `double` value to `int` whose value will be truncated to `0`. Stick with `int`, but work in cents. `first30 = 60;`. Why not use `float` or `double`? Plenty of SO answers for you to search out on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what others have pointed out, all your variables are `int` but some need to be `double` [because you're setting them to `0.6`, etc.]:

```
int watercom;
double fixedrate;
double first30;
double next20;
double next10;
double additional;
int firstcal;
int secondcal;
int thirdcal;
int fourthcal;
```

Comment: Please don't use`double` or `float` for money, work in cents.

Comment: Hmm won't you get a float if you multiply an int times a float? So all the *cal variables should also be floats?

Comment: I didn't know "cents" was a valid C primitive.

Comment: @WeatherVane OP's code was setting an int to 0.6, etc.  Merely correcting that, not whether using 0.6 was appropriate or not

Comment: @ArchonOSX it isn't which is why I didn't use the `code` formatting.

Comment: @CraigEstey in which case you could have corrected the `printf` format specifiers too.

Comment: @WeatherVane No, because the printed output values remained `int`

Comment: Didn't you take on board the comment from @ArchonOSX? This is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( watercom <= 30)
    printf("your bill is %i", &firstcal);
else if (watercom >= 31 && watercom  <= 50)
    printf("your bil is %i", &secondcal);
else if (watercom >= 51 && watercom >= 60)
    printf("your bill is %i", &thirdcal);
else if (watercom >= 61)
    printf("your water bill is %i", fourthcal);
```

There are a number of simplifications that can be applied:

You don't need the `>=` part in each if statement as if `watercom <= 30` then it is implicitly `>= 31`.

Also you don't pass in the `address-of` (`&`) values to `printf`, you pass in the values directly.

You also don't have a default case for when `watercom` is outside the range of expected values:

```
if ( watercom <= 30 )
    printf("your bill is %i", firstcal);
else if ( watercom  <= 50)
    printf("your bill is %i", secondcal);
else if ( watercom <= 60)
    printf("your bill is %i", thirdcal);
else
    printf("your water bill is %i", fourthcal);
```

Comment: Thanks this has simplified my code and the "&" operator is a bad habit!

Answer (score 0):

The algebra of the calculations, as they appeared in the first version of this post, seems all wrong to me. To get you started on that: as well as these `amount * rate` multiplications, you need to be performing an addition --- a fixed rate term, *plus* another amount if you go over the initial allowance, *plus* another amount when you enter the next price bracket, and so on.  To calculate each of these terms, you need to be subtracting the amount of water already-paid-for in previous terms as you go along.

But that's not the question.  You asked why the program was not printing anything at all.  For me, after making a command-line executable out of this using Visual Studio on Windows,  I did replicate that problem: I input the value, then nothing seems to happen.  But then the answer **is** finally printed when I press control-C to halt the program.

To fix this, remove the `\n` from the `scanf` command.

Then proceed to your other problems, which include (a) getting the algebra right, and (b) printing the value (e.g. `firstCal`) not the address (`&firstCal`) of your variables.

Comment: thank you. I removed the \n from the scanf and & operator from the printf statement now to fix the algebra!

Comment: Good luck.  I presume you will also have switched from using `int` to either `float` or `double` as others have suggested.  That means that when you come to print out the results, you'll need a different format specifier:  `%f` or `%g` for `float`s (`%lf` or `%lg` for `double`s).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah your only int is fixedRate. The rest are floats.
Also by what you say in your question that is not what is in your program. If the fixedRate is 10 and the first 30 is at a rate of .6 then if I input 30 I should get fixedRate + (30*.6).
You need to add the fixedRate to all calculations and add the calculations for each tier together for your final amount.

Work the problem on paper before you try to write the program. You should know what output is expected before you test your program. 
Happy Day!